# VBA Paste snip/screenshot into email body

Tags: excel, outlook

I have created a code in excel to create an email with a link and paste a screenshot within the email but im having trouble pasting the screenshot below the email body (ideally i would like it a line below the hyperlink, probably a stupid question but is there a way to amend this code so the screenshot is displayed below the hyperlink rather than at the top of the email?

Thank you in advance, please see code below:

Comment: Please show your existing code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.